# Objective-C - image processing - healing spot brush

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, opencv

Is there any framework (may be, some methods in openCV) or ideas of how can I cut a part of image in user selected area and fill it with other parts of image? Here is example :
[User selected area with house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2tn7.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called inpainting. You can start with OpenCV documentation: [OpenCV inpainting doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) or OpenCV tutorial (it's for Python): [Inpainting tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html)

Comment: Oh, thank you! It will be much easier, when i know, how it's called